# Connection form Invalid credentials

Tags: symfony

When i want to connect with my ID and password i have a error"Invalid credentials" on my flash message . I don’t understand why it doesn’t work

I have 2 User on my DB with the same password
Toto and test

My error :

[image]
My SecurityController  :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Operateur;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/connexion", name="connexion")
     */
public function connexion(Request $request ,AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/connexion.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

}

my security.yaml ( I thought it was the encoder I took off but nothing does )

```
security:
#Permet d'encrypter le mot de passe par l'utilisateur au moment de la saisie
encoders:
    App\Entity\Operateur:
        algorithm: bcrypt

#Permet de définir où les opérateurs sont stockés pour l'autentification
providers:
    badgeuse_db:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Operateur
            property: prenom

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: badgeuse_db
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: connexion
            check_path: connexion
        logout:
            path: /deconnexion
            target: /

access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     #- { path: /profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{% if error %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form class="form-connexion" action="{{ path('connexion') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Prénom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" value="{{ last_username }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  name="_password" placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Connexion" class="btn btn-primary">Connexion</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OperateurRepository")
 */
class Operateur implements UserInterface , \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
 */
private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $utilisateur_windows;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $code_operateur;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\HistoOperateur", mappedBy="operateur")
 */
private $histoOperateurs;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Role", mappedBy="operateur")
 */
private $role;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Nationalite", mappedBy="operateur")
 */
private $nationalites;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Societe", mappedBy="operateur")
 */
private $societes;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email", mappedBy="operateur")
 */
private $emails;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\TempsPasse", inversedBy="operateurs")
 */
private $temps_passes;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Conges", mappedBy="operateurs")
 */
private $conges;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $mot_de_passe;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->histoOperateurs = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->role = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->nationalites = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->societes = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->temps_passes = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->conges = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return ['ROLE_USER'];
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function getPassword()
{ 

}
public function getSalt()
{ 

}
public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getNom(): ?string
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom(string $nom): self
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}


public function getMotDePasse(): ?string 
{
    return $this->mot_de_passe;
}

public function setMotDePasse(string $mot_de_passe): self
{
    $this->mot_de_passe = $mot_de_passe;

    return $this;
}

public function getPrenom(): ?string
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

public function getUtilisateurWindows(): ?string
{
    return $this->utilisateur_windows;
}

public function setUtilisateurWindows(?string $utilisateur_windows): self
{
    $this->utilisateur_windows = $utilisateur_windows;

    return $this;
}

public function getCodeOperateur(): ?string
{
    return $this->code_operateur;
}

public function setCodeOperateur(string $code_operateur): self
{
    $this->code_operateur = $code_operateur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|HistoOperateur[]
 */
public function getHistoOperateurs(): Collection
{
    return $this->histoOperateurs;
}

public function addHistoOperateur(HistoOperateur $histoOperateur): self
{
    if (!$this->histoOperateurs->contains($histoOperateur)) {
        $this->histoOperateurs[] = $histoOperateur;
        $histoOperateur->setOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeHistoOperateur(HistoOperateur $histoOperateur): self
{
    if ($this->histoOperateurs->contains($histoOperateur)) {
        $this->histoOperateurs->removeElement($histoOperateur);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($histoOperateur->getOperateur() === $this) {
            $histoOperateur->setOperateur(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Role[]
 */
public function getRole(): Collection
{
    return $this->role;
}

public function addRole(Role $role): self
{
    if (!$this->role->contains($role)) {
        $this->role[] = $role;
        $role->setOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeRole(Role $role): self
{
    if ($this->role->contains($role)) {
        $this->role->removeElement($role);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($role->getOperateur() === $this) {
            $role->setOperateur(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Nationalite[]
 */
public function getNationalites(): Collection
{
    return $this->nationalites;
}

public function addNationalite(Nationalite $nationalite): self
{
    if (!$this->nationalites->contains($nationalite)) {
        $this->nationalites[] = $nationalite;
        $nationalite->setOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeNationalite(Nationalite $nationalite): self
{
    if ($this->nationalites->contains($nationalite)) {
        $this->nationalites->removeElement($nationalite);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($nationalite->getOperateur() === $this) {
            $nationalite->setOperateur(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Societe[]
 */
public function getSocietes(): Collection
{
    return $this->societes;
}

public function addSociete(Societe $societe): self
{
    if (!$this->societes->contains($societe)) {
        $this->societes[] = $societe;
        $societe->setOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeSociete(Societe $societe): self
{
    if ($this->societes->contains($societe)) {
        $this->societes->removeElement($societe);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($societe->getOperateur() === $this) {
            $societe->setOperateur(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Email[]
 */
public function getEmails(): Collection
{
    return $this->emails;
}

public function addEmail(Email $email): self
{
    if (!$this->emails->contains($email)) {
        $this->emails[] = $email;
        $email->setOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeEmail(Email $email): self
{
    if ($this->emails->contains($email)) {
        $this->emails->removeElement($email);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($email->getOperateur() === $this) {
            $email->setOperateur(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|TempsPasse[]
 */
public function getTempsPasses(): Collection
{
    return $this->temps_passes;
}

public function addTempsPass(TempsPasse $tempsPass): self
{
    if (!$this->temps_passes->contains($tempsPass)) {
        $this->temps_passes[] = $tempsPass;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeTempsPass(TempsPasse $tempsPass): self
{
    if ($this->temps_passes->contains($tempsPass)) {
        $this->temps_passes->removeElement($tempsPass);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Conges[]
 */
public function getConges(): Collection
{
    return $this->conges;
}

public function addConge(Conges $conge): self
{
    if (!$this->conges->contains($conge)) {
        $this->conges[] = $conge;
        $conge->addOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeConge(Conges $conge): self
{
    if ($this->conges->contains($conge)) {
        $this->conges->removeElement($conge);
        $conge->removeOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

//encode et decode l'objet user en session
/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}
/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
}
```

}

Comment: You should have to look into the profiler - then you'll see whats wrong

Comment: If your are using Symfony 4, for making login form you can simply use "php bin/console make:auth". You will find more help here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup

Comment: I don’t know where to look in the profiler for my error Rebru

I'll try your solution Hytsar

Comment: Are you trying to connect with **toto** or **Toto**? You are using the property: `prenom` to connect, but I see `username` in the form? Same field? Can you show `App\Entity\Operateur` please?

Comment: Yes i try it but no change . I have updated my post Zak

Comment: Your `getPassword()` method does not return the password so how it can be validated? Also is your password properly encoded? Also don't use snake_case names for entity properties, this feels like 90's anyway if you ask me. Symfony assumes camelCase property names.

Comment: I have not yet managed the encoding password , so i have to manage him at first?

and for my function getPassword() i need to return password exactly ? for authenticate me ?

Comment: 1. Please update the question with the current code 2. Please don't paste code and errors inside comments, but update the question instead

Comment: Sorry emix first time for me i use stackoverflow :s 

So Zak , i try it and on my validation i have error " The key "_username" must be a string